# the specified child already has a parent .you must call removeView()

Tags: android-layout, android-view

For some reason, I keep receiving the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: the specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent view

I am using the following code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listitem);
    //url is fetched from another class
    readWebpage(imdbUrl);
}

private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //textView.setText(result);
        displayMoviesList(result);
    }
}

public void readWebpage(String imdbUrl) {
}

public void displayMoviesList(String result) {
    JSONObject responseObj = null; 
    try {
        responseObj = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject Obj = responseObj.getJSONObject("results");
        JSONArray moviesListObj = Obj.getJSONArray("result");

        for(int i=0 ;i<moviesListObj.length();i++) {
            JSONObject e = moviesListObj.getJSONObject(i);
            cover[i] = e.getString("cover");
            title[i] = e.getString("title");
            year[i] = e.getString("year");
            director[i] = e.getString("director");
            rating[i] = e.getString("rating");
            details[i] = e.getString("details");
        }

        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);
        imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageID);
        progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingBar);
        //new loadImageTask().execute(cover[i].toString());
        new loadImageTask().execute( URL);// it calls another function..
        TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.titleID);
        title.setText("TEXT");
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.addView(imgView);
        tr.addView(title);
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        //Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
```

I am not sure why I'm receiving the error, but it appears to be being generated while I am adding it to the view.

Comment: Please be more specific with what is going wrong. I.E. what is the error message you're receiving? What line is it being thrown on? Etc.

Comment: Error is coming at line : tr,addView(imgView);

Comment: error  is : java.lang.IllgalStateException: the specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent view

Comment: @TroyAlford Tagging .could you please help. Error is in displayMoviesList.

Comment: I updated your code to help you get more attention - unfortunately, I don't know anything about `Android` - so I'm not able to provide much help.

Comment: Thnks. I got what is the mistake. I was creating the rows in xml file as well in java file. We are supposed to create a place only. Please close this post

Comment: Please post the solution you discovered as an Answer and mark your own answer as "Correct". :) This way future searchers who find this question and are having a similar problem can see it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is that we either we define the rows in .xml file or in our .java file. I was adding the rows dynamically in my java file and using addView. So in .xml file we cannot add another view (we should not add rows for the same).